# Websocket failure to connect : React.js mongoDB express

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I am currently working on user authentication on my web, I can create account and login locally but It shows error when I was testing in my domain. Thank you!

error message below:

**WebSocketClient.js:16 WebSocket connection to 'my_domain' failed: **

- I am using react.js on my web
- I am using heroku to deploy my web
- I am running my server in 4000
- /Cards is the page after I success to login

index.js (my server)

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoutes = require("./Routes/AuthRoutes");
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
require("dotenv").config();

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Sever started on 4000");
});

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB Atlas!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:3000",
    ],
    method: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", authRoutes);
```

Login.js (my login page)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "../Login.css";

function Login() {
  const [cookies] = useCookies([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (cookies.jwt) {
      navigate("/Cards");
    }
  }, [cookies, navigate]);

  const [values, setValues] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
  const generateError = (error) =>
    toast.error(error, {
      position: "bottom-right",
    });
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:4000/login",
        {
          ...values,
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
      if (data) {
        if (data.errors) {
          const { email, password } = data.errors;
          if (email) generateError(email);
          else if (password) generateError(password);
        } else {
          navigate("/Cards");
        }
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
  };
```

I am currently working on user authentication on my web, I can create account and login locally but It shows error when I was testing in my domain. Thank you!